# Can I declare optional values in a variable

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var x = aa || 3 || dd;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Variables</h1>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

I wish to create variable with optional values

```
var a = x || b || 2
```

like if x is not undefined a should print value of x and so on

Comment: What is the issue here ? It should work as it is.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia no as u can see in the post its not working

Comment: Since variable is not declared you can use `typeof` to check that. See the answer posted by @hhayashi

Comment: add `var aa;` at the js block

Comment: Why are you using variables which were never declared? That's never a good idea.

Comment: @torazaburo actually he forgot to declare it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aa is not defined in your question

Defining 
`var aa = 0; (or) 
var aa = null; (or) 
var aa = ''; (or)
var aa = undefined;` will print 3.

```js
var aa = 0;
var x = aa || 3 || dd;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Variables</h1>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: But if it is `var x = aa || dd || 3;` It will fail, then again  `dd` need to be defined

Comment: Also, if `3` is in the middle, `dd` can never be the value. `3` will always be truthy, so if `aa` is undefined `3` will always be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will work, unless `x` or `b` are falsy values. Like if `x === ''` and `b === 0`, then `a` will be set to `2`.

You could do something like `var a = typeof x === 'undefined' ? (typeof b === 'undefined' ? 2 : b) : x` if you want to set `a` to the first defined value.

Comment: Do you know what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Use try catch

```js
var a=0;
try {
  //  a= x || b || 2;
   a = typeof x === 'undefined' ? (typeof b === 'undefined' ? 2 : b) : x
  alert(a);
}
catch(err) {
 alert("Error Occured "+err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = (x > 0)? x : (if(b > 0) ? b : 2);
```

here instead of undefined i have used 0 as the condition 
if x> 0 then x else b > 0 then b else 2